# How to SELECT a JSON column in MySQL and return as an Array()

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I have a JSON column (called json_col) in a MySQL table:

{'a':9, 'b':8, 'c':7}

I want to select the column "json_col" with each of its keys and values and return it as an array() so I can process it in PHP.

How do I do that?

I tried JSON_EXTRACT() but that requires me to specify the json element and it only returns the corresponding value.

Here is "my effort":

```
  $query_string = '
    SELECT JSON_EXTRACT( json_col, "$.a" )
    FROM settings
    WHERE id = "4"
    LIMIT 1
  ';
  $result = mysqli_query( $GLOBALS['db_link'], $query_string ) or die( mysqli_error( $GLOBALS['db_link'] ) );
  $row = mysqli_fetch_row( $result );
  mysqli_free_result( $result );
```

When I echo $row[0] I get the value of "a" which is 9!

Comment: Show us your efforts and where you **exactly** have problems. Are you having **issues selecting the json column**? Or are you having problems converting the json string to an array **after you successfully loaded the value from the database**?

Comment: Sure thing @Rafal! Updated my OQ!

Comment: Executing the sql `SELECT json_col FROM settings WHERE id = "4" LIMIT 1` would give you `'{'a':9, 'b':8, 'c':7}'`, correct?

Comment: Exactly @Rafal. Did that in an earlier development step. So maybe I need to then use PHP to breakdown the JSON data into an array()...correct? I was thinking and hoping that maybe the array could be produced by MySQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply Change your query to select the json:

```
$query_string = '
    SELECT json_col
    FROM settings
    WHERE id = "4"
    LIMIT 1
';
```

Execute your query as you did before

```
$result = mysqli_query( $GLOBALS['db_link'], $query_string ) or die( mysqli_error( $GLOBALS['db_link'] ) );
$row = mysqli_fetch_row( $result );
```

And then convert it to an array with [json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

```
$myArray = json_decode($row['json_col'], true);
```

You can check its values like this:

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($myArray);
echo "</pre>";
```